# Best way of applying gradle build plugins?

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

You can apply gradle plugins in Kotlin DSL as follow:

1.

```
plugins {
    kotlin("android")
}
```

2. 

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-android`
}
```

3. 

```
plugins {
        id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    }
```

Are these all equivalent, or what's the consensus today, has one of them more pros than the others?